# Quality loss in digital photography

Tags: image

I have a poster on the wall and I click a picture of it with my phone camera. What kind of quality losses would this picture suffer. I was thinking the top few losses would be blurriness, loss of colour contrast and maybe some noise.

I eventually want to be able to take an image in digital form and apply these losses computationally to the pristine image. Any ideas?

Comment: There will also be lens shape (barrel) distortion and chromatic aberration.. and not just loss of contrast but a complicated colourspace transform. Also compression artifacts. Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a poster, you will probably also get some moire patterns depending on the quality of the lens and the resolution of the sensor. This is because the poster on the wall is only made up of 4 colours (CMYK) in a pattern. As blueshift pointed out you will also get a distortion from the lens, especially from a very wide lens like on a cell phone, and chromatic aberration.

Depending on the type of camera you want to emulate, you will also get other types of blurring, like smudge and dirt on the lens on a cell phone camera. Other light sources in the scene will probably also cause some lens flare.

If the lighting is bad, most cell phone cameras add a lot of gain as well, wich will show the sensor noise.

Comment: Thanks guys. I did some research and found that there is a discipline called "Computational Photography" that deals with this problem. Can I take the clicked image and the original image and then subtract the 2 to understand what kind of quality loss occurs? Will this quality loss be specific to specific images or will it be generic?